# How to build model if the data dont have corelation each other's

Tags: regression, cnn

I have 2 datasets, call them dataset A and dataset B. Then I want to predict dataset A using dataset B as input using regression model.

dataset A format:

[image]

[image]

dataset A shape(15000,1)

dataset B format:

[image]
[image]

dataset B shape(15000,89)

I've tried to make a model using CNN, I have good training results. However, when I test the model using new data, the model cannot predict the data correctly.

Training data code:

```
Insole = pd.read_csv('1225_Rwalk10min1_list.txt', header=None, low_memory=False)
SIData =  np.array(Insole)

df = pd.read_csv('1225_Rwalk10min.csv', low_memory=False)
columns = ['Fx']
selected_df = df[columns]
FCDatas = selected_df[:15000]

SmartInsole = np.array(SIData[:15000])
FCData = np.array(FCDatas)

scaler_x = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaler_x.fit(SmartInsole)
xscale = scaler_x.transform(SmartInsole)

scaler_y = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaler_y.fit(FCData)
yscale = scaler_y.transform(FCData)

sample_size = xscale.shape[0] # number of samples in train set
time_steps  = xscale.shape[1] # number of features in train set
input_dimension = 1               # each feature is represented by 1 number

train_data_reshaped = xscale.reshape(sample_size,time_steps,input_dimension)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train_data_reshaped, yscale, test_size=0.20, random_state=2)

model = Sequential(name="model_conv1D")

n_timesteps = train_data_reshaped.shape[1] #13
n_features  = train_data_reshaped.shape[2] #1 

model.add(Input(shape=(n_timesteps,n_features)))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=7, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_features, activation='sigmoid')))

model.summary()
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001), metrics=['mse'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=200,validation_split=0.1, verbose=2)
```

Model Loss :
[image]

Training Process:
[image]

Training data predictions:
[image]

Test model use other data code:

```
Test_Insole = pd.read_csv('1225_Rwalk10min2_list.txt', header=None, low_memory=False)
TestSIData =  np.asarray(Test_Insole)

Test_df = pd.read_csv('1225_Rwalk10min2.csv', low_memory=False)
Test_columns = ['Fx']
Test_selected_df = Test_df[Test_columns]
Test_FCDatas = Test_selected_df[:4200]

test_SmartInsole = np.array(TestSIData[:4200])
test_FCData = np.array(Test_FCDatas)

Test_scaler_x = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
Test_scaler_x.fit(test_SmartInsole)
Test_xscale = Test_scaler_x.transform(test_SmartInsole)

Test_scaler_y = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
Test_scaler_y.fit(test_FCData)
Test_yscale = Test_scaler_y.transform(test_FCData)

test_sample_size = Test_xscale.shape[0] # number of samples in train set
test_time_steps  = Test_xscale.shape[1] # number of features in train set
test_input_dimension = 1               # each feature is represented by 1 number

test_train_data_reshaped = Test_xscale.reshape(test_sample_size,test_time_steps,test_input_dimension)

model.evaluate(test_train_data_reshaped, Test_yscale)
Test_xX_model = model.predict(test_train_data_reshaped)
```

Test model predictions result:
[image]

Comment: Sounds like your model is over-fitting.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that your features *should* be predictive of the outcome?

Answer (score 3):

If you have good results on the validation set and very poor results on the test data, i.e. data that has not been seen during training the model, it is a clear sign of over-fitting. Have you tried using other algorithms? Since you are dealing with mainly continuous variables you can try using Quantile Transformer which will scale your data into a normal gaussian distribution. Also, in the data preparation steps check for data quality and remove outliers.

Comment: How does a Gaussian feature distribution help?

Comment: It was just a suggestion, since most ml models perform well when the data is normally distributed, however this is not required when working with decision tree based models. Choosing the appropriate data transformation is part of the experimentation and is dependent of the specific use case.

Comment: Few models have any expectation about data being Gaussian. There are reasons for liking Gaussian *error* distributions, but that is distinct from feature distribution.

Comment: Agreed, that's why it's important to reverse transform the features to understand the corresponding value in the original feature space when using techniques like partial dependence plots to interpret the ml model.

Comment: So then what’s the point of transforming the features to give Gaussian distributions?